# Defining shifts based on hourly work demand

Tags: algorithm, math

I have to plan the shifts for a set of employees, based on hourly work demand and I would like to find the most efficient and analytical way to do so.

As You can see from the following image, the orange line is the minimum number of employees that I need to have for every single hour (from 8 to 9, from 9 to 10 and so on). The blue columns represent the number of employees that are planned in that hour with the current shifts roster.

[image: Work demand]

To achieve this, I need to plan the shifts for every employee. The following image is an example of the daily shifts. You can see for example that the light green employee works from 10 to 16, while blue employee works from 12 to 16 and so on.

[image: Shifts plan]

The problem is to find an algorithm that can give you the best solution considering that:

- I have an hourly request of employees (from 8 to 9 I need 3 employees, from 10 to 11 I need 4 employees and so on)
- I have a set of shift types, defined with the start hour and the duration (for example a shift type starts at 8 and last 8 hours, or starts at 12 and lasts 4 hours)

Thanks everyone for the support

EDIT:

Due to the fact that the problem is not analytical and might use a iteration algorithm to solve, I add some details to let everyone have the big picture.

- The work demand is 24 hours long, so for every day I have 24 points and so 24 different hourly employee requirements
- The shifts that I can use are these:

  - from 6 to 14
  - from 7 to 15
  - from 8 to 16
  - from 9 to 17
  - from 10 to 18
  - from 13 to 21
  - from 14 to 22
  - from 15 to 23
  - from 23 to 7
- I have about 200 employees, but this should work also for something like 500
- the maximum work demand needed is about 40, but this should work also for something like 70

Hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: This is a variant of the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: You should tell us what values you car vary.  Shift start time?  Shift durations?  Any shifts already fixed?  Or limited in variation (e.g. shifts cannot be shorter than 4 hours, cannot start after 12, etc.)? Amount of employees?

Comment: I can vary start and duration of shifts, I have a set of them, declared at first. I have a predefined hourly work demand, not editable. I have potentially unlimited employees, but I need to find the solution that uses the minimum amount. Thanks

Comment: You have two optimization goals: decrease excessive employees number for every hour sum and decrease the number of employees used. As an option, you need to assign weights to them.

Comment: The main goal is to decrease the number of employees used. the solution I think it's something related to [exact cover](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exact-cover-problem-algorithm-x-set-1/) where X represents the hours and S the shift types. But I have to cover each hour multiple times, not only once.

Comment: I would suggest using a LP solver if your constraints on the shift types are a bit complicated.
That will allow for a simple code, simple to modify/update, and the run time/efficiency of LP solvers is really good.

Comment: As for the optimization criteria, when there is more than one, you can have a look at [MCDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-criteria_decision_analysis) if you want a more subtle way of dealing with the trade-offs between your criteria than to optimize a linear combination of your criteria.

Comment: I guess you have more restrictions you don't tell us about.  Otherwise it's simple:  Add a 1-hour shift for each hour where something is missing until all demands are fulfilled.  Then start combining shifts which end where another one starts until this isn't possible anymore.  But then you will end up with shifts with gaps.  You could ask an employee to take two shifts a day, one in the morning and one in the evening (e. g.) and still count them as one employee, but I guess this not what you want.  So I suggest to try to fill gaps to combine shifts if possible.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I have some simple constraints for the shifts. For example every employee can have just one shift per day and the shift could not be very short, let's say 4 hours minimum

Comment: Interesting. So three employees work from 8 to 13, one works from 10 to 15, and the last works from 11 to 16. Is that correct?

Comment: yes but this is just an example, built very easy to understand. The real scenario is a lot bigger so it wouldn't be possible to solve it in a simple way

Comment: You should edit the question to include the extra information you've provided here in the comments. And you should edit the question to tell us how big the real scenario is. In other words, what are the real constraints on the problem. How many employees? How many hours? Is it really only one day at time with 8 hours to cover, or a week at 24 hours a day (168 hours), or more. The set-cover problem doesn't have an exact solution that runs in polynomial time, so you need to come up with an approximate solution, or use brute force. That choice can't be made without knowing the constraints.

Comment: I have added some further details. In the meantime, I wrote a brute force algorithm in Java. It clearly works, but for every day it takes about 5 minutes. Therefore I need something a little bit faster (even though approximate in case). Thank You